# Cannot replace standard login form with custom in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-security

When i'm going to localhost/SpringMVC/login the server points me to a default login page, not the page i've created. Security.xml seems to be included correctly, as  works fine. I`m using Spring Security 4.0.0
Here's my security config:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/forRegisteredUsersOnly" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login 
        login-page='/login'
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
</http>
```

web.xml:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/webapp-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/webapp-security.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>webapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

LoginController.java :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLoginForm(@RequestParam(required=false) String authFailed, String logout) {
        String message="";
        if(authFailed != null) {
            message = "Invalid username or password, try again !";
        } else if (logout != null) {
            message = "Logged Out successfully, login again to continue!";
        }
        return new ModelAndView("login", "message", message);
    }
}
```

ViewResolver then maps "login" to /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp (mapping works fine for other pages)

Update:
I don't know why, but my login form can be found at localhost/SpringMVC/login.html. How can i change it to localhost/SpringMVC/login ?

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes for value of login-page and try by adding default-target-url .

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
     <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
     <intercept-url pattern="/forRegisteredUsersOnly" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
     <form-login 
          login-page="/login"
          default-target-url="/home"
          authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
          login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" />
     <logout logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
</http>
```

Comment: I changed to login-page="/login", but the problem still remains

Comment: The problem has been solved by changing login-page="/login" to login-page="/login.jsp".

Comment: glad to see, you fixed it.